# How align legends with text in google chart

Tags: bar-chart

Using google chart develop the bar chart, place legends on top right but legends not align with text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaLXZ.png)

Comment: add some code to look in to or a minimal example to reproduce your error

Comment: Please refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/ykj45mh7/ as example, look at the alignment of green rectangle and text 'Last Year Revenue'